# Where does the "Ask Question" title prompt come from? Can we change it? To what?

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions

When you [ask a question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) on the main site, the Title box has a prompt that reads:

> what's your the analysis of biblical text question? be specific.

I'm not sure why, but I've never noticed the text until today.  A variation of this prompt is present on other sites too.  Generally, the prompt makes sense:

> [what's your history question? be specific.](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)
>
> [what's your scientific skepticism question? be specific.](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

The capitalization can be broken at times:

> [what's your christianity question? be specific.](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

But our prompt is:

1. grammatically incorrect,
2. limited to one of the [five](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/faq) types of questions we have, and
3. really wordy.

Can we fix the text that seems to be site-specific?  (That would be "the analysis of biblical text", if I'm not mistaken.)  What would be better wording?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a [meta-tag:bug], [meta-tag:feature-request], or [meta-tag:discussion].  It bugs me and unless there's some way for us to fix it on our own, there's no point in discussing it. ;-)

Comment: Using the [new search feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100/1438 "Now with exclusive AND!") on MSE, I found [four results](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search-new?q=%22what%27s+your%22+%22be+specific.%22&submit=search).  None helped.

Comment: This is also a bit dodgy: ["Questions on Biblical Hermeneutics - Stack Exchange are expected to relate to the analysis of biblical text within the scope defined in the FAQ."](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/faq#close)

Comment: And ["Is your question about the analysis of biblical text?"](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) in the sidebar. I'm guessing they all come from the same place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done:

[image: What's your hermeneutics question? Be specific.]

I lower-cased hermeneutics, so's to not go completely overboard with the caps.

Answer (score 5):

> What would be better wording?

what's your ***Hermeneutics*** question? be specific.

Comment: And can we have a capital 'W' and 'B'??

Comment: On the capitalization: [apparently not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119784/1438 "I'm surprised Jeff didn't threaten to beat us with his giant S.").